# Entity Framework Code-First : How to design?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a MS-SQL table as shown below.

Users Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]( 
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL    Primary Key,
[UserAccount] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL       Unique,
[Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[UserEmail] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[JoinDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
[LoginDate] [datetime2](7) NULL)
```

Roles Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Roles](
[RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL    Primary Key,
[RoleName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL      Unique,
[Note] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[RegistDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL)
```

UsersInRoles Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersInRoles](
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[SetDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[UserId] ASC,
[RoleId] ASC)WITH (
PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersInRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([RoleId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Roles] ([RoleId]) GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UsersInRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId]) GO
```

I'm trying to express in EF Code-First of this.

User Entity Class

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserAccount { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
}
```

Role Entity Class

```
public class Role
{
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistDate { get; set; }
}
```

UsersInRole Entity Class

```
public class UsersInRole
{   
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime SetDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem of the foreign key, How should designed UsersInRoles?

Please let me know if there is a better design.

Comment: I'd personally suggest just using the Visual Studio Entity Model wizard, and have a model generated for you based on your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really code first if you are designing your database and then making the code conform, is it?  Sounds like you should have a roles collection defined on your User class and then let EntityFramework do the work of building that intermediate table. It will handle the FK relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running the following code, so I aren't 100% sure.
However I would start out with something like ...

in your domain classes

```
public class User
{
 public Guid UserId { get; set; }
 public string UserAccount { get; set; }
 public string Password { get; set; }
 public string UserEmail { get; set; }
 public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime LoginDate { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
 public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
 public string RoleName { get; set; }
 public string Note { get; set; }
 public DateTime RegistDate { get; set; }
}


public class UsersInRole
{   
 public DateTime SetDate { get; set; }
 virtual User User { get; set; }
 virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

in your context you need

```
public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

public DbSet<UsersInRole> UsersInRoles { get; set; }
```

optionally you might want to include

```
public virtual  ICollection<UsersInRole> Roles { get; private set; }
```

in the User class

and/or

```
public virtual  ICollection<UsersInRole> Users { get; private set; }
```

in the role class
Which will keep the same data structure.